# Execute exe from WinForm in non-modal

Tags: c#, winforms

I wish to execute an exe program from a winforms button. I am using the below code which works. The problem is the winform goes into a blocked state and I cannot interact with it until the exe program is closed. I would like to interact with both the winform and the executed program.

How can I make the executed program non-modal?

```
    public static void ExecuteCommand(string workingDirectory, 
                                           string cvsExePath, string arguments)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo exeProcess = new ProcessStartInfo(cvsExePath
                                       , " " + arguments.Trim()); 
        exeProcess.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
        exeProcess.UseShellExecute = false;
        exeProcess.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        exeProcess.RedirectStandardError = true;
        exeProcess.CreateNoWindow = false;
        Process proc = Process.Start(exeProcess);
    }
```

Comment: i don't really know much about modal vs non modal methods, but could you not use a separate Thread instead?

Comment: Have you posted full code sample? I have no idea, how to make calling process to wait without any extra-code, like `Process.WaitForExit()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a thread and the thread execute this exe

this is how to create threads :
[How to: Create and Terminate Threads (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)